# How to pass array variable to function and solve out the no command found error

Tags: ubuntu

I'm new in this so please anyone can help me to figure out this problem, I've write all code but when i run this command in shell by using `./work.sh host.txt` here host is a text file from where we'll read two values one is a local host and the other one is `br414b-01.csc.tntech.edu` then in output the text file lines should be displayed but there displays

```
cat: localhost: No such file or directory
cat: br414b-01.csc.tntech.edu: no such file or directory.
```

I just want to show the local host and in next line `br414b-01.csc.tntech.edu`. I've added my all code and one thing please also tell me the meaning of this line how should i pass global variable of array in calling function

> To call the function, your script will simply execute the following
>   code:
>
> ```
> read_hosts $@
> ```
>
> The $@ passes the script parameter (the name of the file containing
>   the hosts) to the function. In the above algorithm, hosts_array is a
>   global variable, so the function's caller will be able to use the
>   global variable to access the host names.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#function name

read_hosts(){

    #function body
    hosts=$(cat $1)
    count=1
    for host in $hosts; do   
    #make an array equal to the hosts.txt file data.
    hosts_array[$count]=$host
    count=`expr $count + 1`     
    done    


    done=0      
while [ $done == 0 ]; do 

        echo "(P)ing a host"
        echo "(S)sh to host"
        echo "(T)race toute to host"
        echo "(N)slookup host"
    echo "(Q)uit"

        read -p "Please enter a command: " cmd

          case $cmd in

          P|p)  
         pick_host "$hosts"
         echo "ping -c 1 ${hosts_array[$which_host]}"
                 ping -c 1 ${hosts_array[$which_host]}       
         ;;
      S|s)
         pick_host "$hosts"
         read -p "Username: " user
         echo "ssh $user@${hosts_array[$which_host]}"
         ssh $user@${hosts_array[$which_host]}
         ;;
          T|t)
         pick_host "$hosts"
         echo "traceroute ${hosts_array[$which_host]}"
         traceroute ${hosts_array[$which_host]}
         ;;
          N|n)
         pick_host "$hosts"
         echo "nslookup ${hosts_array[$which_host]}"
         nslookup ${hosts_array[$which_host]}
         ;;
      Q|q) 
         done=1;
         exit
         ;;
           *)
         echo "Bad choice";
         ;;
      esac
done
}


pick_host(){

        count=1
 for host in `cat $1`;
 do echo "$count)$host"
 count=`expr $count + 1`
 done

 read -p "Which host " which_host
 while [ $which_host -ge 1 -a $which_host -lt $count ]; do
 echo "valid"
 done

}


read_hosts $@
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting?

Comment: @choroba i can send screenshot if you want

Comment: It wouldn't help. Having a code I can run and understand would, though.

Comment: i've uploaded all the code just copy and paste in your terminal

Comment: just copy and paste in your shell or terminal i've pasted line by line here ..

Comment: You should have selected the code and pressed Ctrl+K, too.

Comment: ok please wait then

Comment: @choroba i've re-arranged the code thanks for telling me this option :)

Comment: Try adding `set -xv` at line 2 of your script and running it again. It'll show you what shell sees and runs.

Comment: after count=1 or with this ? can you tell me a proper line if you don't mind because i've never used this set command

Comment: Line number 2 is the line below the shebang line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pick_host` is called with `"$hosts"`, i.e. the contents of the `host.txt` file. In the function, though, you say

```
for host in `cat $1`
```

But `$1` is the first argument to `pick_host`, i.e. "$hosts". You're trying to `cat` hostnames, not filenames.